# Show last X output lines

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to output only the last five lines of an Ansible shell output, for example?
Maybe using loops?

Example:

```yaml
  - name: Running Migrations
    ansible.builtin.shell: /some-script-produces-lot-of-output.sh
    register: ps
  - debug: var=ps.stdout_lines
```

The `debug` task should only output the last five lines.

Comment: Use a python array slice: `debug: msg={{ ps.stdout_lines[-6:] }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Python's slicing notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/2123530) for this:

```yaml
- debug: 
    var: ps.stdout_lines[-5:]
```

Will output the 5 lines from the end of the list (hence the negative value) up until the end of the list.

---

Given the tasks

```yaml
- shell: |-
    for idx in $(seq 1 10)
    do
      printf "line%d\n" "${idx}"
    done
  register: ps

- debug:
    var: ps.stdout_lines[-5:]
```

This yields:

```
TASK [shell] ******************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ps.stdout_lines[-5:]:
  - line6
  - line7
  - line8
  - line9
  - line10
```

Comment: I was off by one:)

Comment: You might win another battle.